# Where can you store model-related data that is not stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my view (form partial).

```
<%= f.select(:transaction_type, ["For Sale", "For Trade"], :prompt => true) %>
```

I would like to move `["For Sale", "For Trade"]` out of the view.

My assumption is that it should go in the model, however I am not sure how do this. I realize I could put it in a helper very easily, but I'm not sure it makes the most sense to keep this sort of data there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to reuse this set of array, or you want to make sure it is easily modifiable, keep it in a model as

```
class MyClass
     COLLECTION_ARR = ["For Sale", "For Trade"]
end
```

And you can then modify you view as

```
<%= f.select(:transaction_type,User::COLLECTION_ARR , :prompt => true) %>
```